# How to compile my c# solution with msbuild from command line

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, mono

I have a c# solution (open source, available here: https://github.com/tzachshabtay/MonoAGS) which I can compile fine from Visual Studio 2017 (Dot net framework) and from VS for Mac (Mono). I can also compile it with msbuild on Travis CI successfully on both linux and mac (https://github.com/tzachshabtay/MonoAGS/blob/master/.travis.yml).

What I can't do, is compile it on command-line from Windows 10 on my local machine. I'd like to be able to compile it both for DotNet Framework and Mono.
So I tried using MSBuild from both the mono installation and from the `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017` (note: I want to be able to install on windows even if vs2017 is not installed, though on the local machine vs2017 is installed, don't know if it matters).
Both installations are for the latest versions as of today.

This is the error I get from msbuild on mono (`PATH` was set to `%programfiles(x86)%\Mono\bin`):

> Project "C:\Github\MonoAGS\MonoAGS.sln" (1) is building "C:\Github\MonoAGS\Source\Tests\Tests.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
>   Project "C:\Github\MonoAGS\Source\Tests\Tests.csproj" (2) is building "C:\Github\MonoAGS\Source\AGS.API\AGS.API.csproj"
>    (3) on node 1 (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)).
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props(29,11): error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\
>   Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Microsoft.Common.props" was not found. Also, tried to find "15.0\Microsoft.Common.prop
>   s" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths
>   are defined in "C:\Program Files\Mono\lib\mono\msbuild\15.0\bin\MSBuild.dll.config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths. [C:\Github\MonoAGS\Source\AGS.
>   API\AGS.API.csproj]

And here's the error I get from msbuild from build tools (`PATH` was set to `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`):

> Project "C:\Github\MonoAGS\Source\Tests\Tests.csproj" (2) is building "C:\Github\MonoAGS\Source\AGS.API\AGS.API.csproj" (3) on node 1 (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)).
>   C:\Github\MonoAGS\Source\AGS.API\AGS.API.csproj : error MSB4247: Could not load SDK Resolver. A manifest file exists, but the path to the SDK Resolver DLL file could not be found. Manifest file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.Build.NuGet
>   SdkResolver\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.xml'. SDK resolver path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtens
>   ions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll

As for the mono error, the `MSBuild\15.0` folder exists but `Microsoft.Common.props` is not there (and I couldn't find it anywhere else on that machine).

As for the build tools error, the `CommonExtensions` folder exists but there is no `Microsoft` folder in it.

The command I'm trying is:
`msbuild /p:Configuration=DEBUG /p:Platform="Any CPU" MonoAGS.sln`

Why doesn't it work? What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to compile my c# solution with msbuild from command line

For the build tools error, you should install the component **NuGet package manager** by Visual Studio Installer:

[image]

When we use the Visual Studio build tool to build our project, we also need to install some of the necessary components for our project.

For the mono error, since I do not have mono ENV, I could not specify the directly reason for that error, if possible, you can try to install [Mono framework](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-mac). If it not helps, you can open a new thread with mono and msbuild tags.

**Update:**

> How do I install it with command-line, btw (for setting up a script)?

Yes, you can use `vs_buildtools.exe` to install that component ID **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet**:

```
vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet --quiet
```

Note: You should rename `vs_buildtools__2048890300.15156xxxx.exe` to vs_buildtools.exe, then use `vs_buildtools.exe` to install it.

Check the [Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2017#officesharepoint-build-tools) and [Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tonight and update (if you're part of the product, btw, a better error message would be appreciated). How do I install it with command-line, btw (for setting up a script)? As for mono, I do have it installed (and your links are for Mac, where the problem is on Windows).

Comment: Thanks, it works. Note that I also had to install .net core workflow (even though I'm using framework, see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2532). As for command line instructions, found a link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017 (ah, nvm, saw you posted an update, thanks!)

Comment: @tzachs, Yes, we could install it by the command line `vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet --quiet`.